# Features for gesture recognition

Tags: machine-learning, gesture

I would like to create an application which can learn to classify a sequence of points drawn by a user, e.g. something like handwriting recognition.  If the data point consists of a number of (x,y) pairs (like the pixels corresponding to a gesture instance), what are the best features to compute about the instance which would make for a good multi-class classifier (e.g. SVM, NN, etc)?  Particularly if there are limited training examples provided.

Comment: This is a vague and very open-ended question. What have you tried so far? What kind of performance do you need/expect? How limited are the training examples? I could give a bunch of suggestions but they might not be suitable.

Comment: The number of instances would be dozens, perhaps 3-5 distinct classes.A user interactively traces a simple gesture/shape on a 2d grid, e.g. a diagonal line, an arc, a zigzag, etc. The raw data will consist of (x,y) pairs traced on the screen, or possibly a 3-d version with (x,y,z) triplets.I have considered taking a bounding box around the gesture, turning it into an image (white background, black shape), downsampling it to say 6x6 and using the 36 pixel values as features (or using PCA to reduce dimensionality more). I suspect higher-level features based on curvature may be better?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were you, I would find the data points that correspond with corners, end points and intersections, use those as features and discard the intermediate points. You could include the angle or some other descriptor of these interest points as well.

For detecting interest points you could use a [Harris detector](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corner_detection#The_Harris_.26_Stephens_.2F_Plessey_.2F_Shi-Tomasi_corner_detection_algorithm), you could then use the gradient value at that point as a simple descriptor. Alternatively you could go with a more fancy method like [SIFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform).

You could use the descriptor of every pixel in your downsampled image and then classify with SVM. The disadvantage of that is that there would be a large amount of uninteresting data points in the feature vector.

An alternative would be to not approach it as a classification problem but as a template matching problem (fairly common in [computer-vision](/questions/tagged/computer-vision)). In this case a gesture can be specified as an arbitrary number of interest points, completely leaving out the non-interesting data. A certain threshold percentage of an instance's points has to match a template for a positive identification. For example, when matching the corner points of an instance of 'R' against the template for 'X', the bottom right point should match, being end points in the same position orientation, but the others are too dissimilar, giving a fairly low score and the identification R=X will be rejected.